# return the values of multiple ( multiple select )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a dynamic form that duplicate itself for bulk insertion .

example : my form has multiple select

```
<select name="type[]" multiple>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
</select>
```

when I duplicate it like this

```
<select name="type[]" multiple>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
</select>

<select name="type[]" multiple>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
</select>
```

and select for example all of the options in the two selects it return something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 2 
    [2] => 3 
    [4] => 1 
    [5] => 2 
    [6] => 3 
)
```

with this . i don't know what is selected in the first select and what is selected in the 2nd one 
how can i do that

---- EDIT -----

i dublicate the form by jqyery when click on input

```
 jQuery("body").on("click", '.duplicate', function(){

            $(".newform"). append(jQuery(".form").html());
            return false;

        });
```

where the button  that duplicate has class  (.duplicate)
and the form in div has class (.form)
and have empty div has class (.newform)

when i click Button (.duplicate) it duplicate the (.form) into ( .newform )

----- EDIT ------

i modified the javascript to fit the accepted answer

```
jQuery("body").on("click", '.duplicate', function(){
 $key = $(".newform>div").length;
 $(".newform"). append(jQuery(".form").html().replace(new RegExp('\\[\\]\\[\\]', 'g'),'['+$key+'][]'));
});
```

i just counted the div inside the (.newform) to make it as a key 
then replace every [][] to []['key']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them to have the same name, always, you can do this:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['type']))
        var_dump($_POST['type']);
?>
<form method="POST">

    <select name="type[1][]" multiple>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="type[2][]" multiple>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

They will become a multidimensional array in the server side.

Result for all options selected:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: the problem that i duplicate the div with all its content , to change the key it will be defecult , i know it's not impossible to do that , but if any easiest way to duplicate the all div , i tried type[][] but it return something not  expected

Comment: If you duplicate and always keep the same name, you will not be able to know which value belongs to which select. Add your duplication code to your question and I'll see what can be done.

Comment: You're still going to have to do it this way, but use the javascript to add the selects the way they need to be.

Comment: I modified the java script code to make it fit this answer , i will edit my question